# Passing Multi-Value Parameter to Oracle Linked Server in SQL Server from SSRS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services

I'm currently building a report in SSRS using a MSSQL datasource. In that datasource I have a linked Oracle server that I am pulling my base dataset from. I'm trying to pass a multi-value text parameter from SSRS to MSSQL which then will be used in an OPENQUERY to the Oracle DB. Put simply my query in MSSQL looks something like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT id, type, name FROM sample WHERE type IN (''''A'''',''''B'''')'
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(oracledb,''' + @SQL + ''')'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Typically with SSRS, using MSSQL, I can replace the

```
type IN (''''A'''',''''B'''')
```

with

```
type IN (@Parameter)
```

How would I go about doing this when passing the multivalue parameter to the above mentioned query since its using a linkedserver to oracle?

Answer (score 0):

This works for openquery to DB2, but I will point out you're missing a + after @SQL in your example. Once I added that it worked.

`SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(oracledb,''' + @SQL +''')'`